# Mixing Water at Different Temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, temperature

If I have cup of water at room temperature (say, $25^\circ$C).  What would be the resultant temperature if I pour another cup of same amount of water at $100^\circ$C to it?  Is it simply $\frac{25+100}{2}$?

If yes, what if I pour a cup of n times amount of water at $100^\circ$C to it?  Is it simply the sum of all temperature (25+100) divided by the total amount of water $(n+1)$ i.e. $\frac{25+100n}{n+1}$?

I am no expert in Physics. I am just thinking of a way to get a cup of water at roughly, say, $40^\circ$C without using any thermometer.  I know I can obtain water at room temp and $100^\circ$C easily.  But dont know how to get my target temp by mixing water at these 2 different temp.

Answer (score 10):

Heat transfers from hotter water to cooler water until temperatures equalize.

If mass and temperature of the hotter water are $m_H$ and $T_H$, mass and temperature of the cooler water are $m_C$ and $T_C$, specific heat capacity of water is $c$, and equilibrium temperature is $T$, then heat released by hotter water $Q_1$ is

$$Q_1 = c\ m_H  (T_H-T)$$

while the heat absorbed by cooler water $Q_2$ is

$$Q_2 = c\ m_C (T-T_C)$$

Since $Q_1 = Q_2$ you can easily obtain equilibrium temperature as

$$T = \frac{m_H T_H + m_C T_C}{m_C+m_H}$$

Comment: As he is talking about cups, it should be in terms of volume and not mass, right? So I think the answer should include the thermal expansion coefficient somewhere.

Comment: In principle you are right.  However the thermal expansion coefficient is not temperature independent, and even if it would be temperature independent you end up with exponential change of volume.  I think it is much better idea to use data for water's density and recalculate volumes into masses...  You think that I should include that in the text?

Comment: For water at $100^\circ C$, do we have to take into account latent heat?

Comment: @leongz Only if you use vapour instead of liquid water.

Comment: @Pygmalion: This only works due to the constant specific heat of water, which is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to include this. Since the c we are using is most likely going to be from the heat capacity derived at constant volume, either we're keeping the volume constant with pressure in this experiment or, more likely, neglecting the change in density.