# Change in temperature of overflowing container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, fluid-statics, integration

Mixing of identical fluids at different temperatures is simple, as per here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24433/290018

We have a slightly different situation in that the container is overflowing:

A container, with limited capacity, is filled with liquid, say water, at temperature $\Theta$. An additional amount of water, $V_\text{in}$ at temperature $\Theta_\text{in}$ is poured into the container. It mixes instantly and perfectly, and an identical volume overflows.

This situation can be modelled as (note specific heat capacity is assumed constant etc):

$$
\Theta+d\Theta=\frac{\Theta\times\text{capacity}+\Theta_\text{in}\times dV_\text{in}}{\text{capacity}+dV_\text{in}}
$$

This is very similar to the answer above but for an incremental (and infinitely small) volume $dV_\text{in}$ producing an incremental temperature change $d \Theta$.

It is easy to numerically loop the volume to be added in small increments and thus obtain the curve of $\Theta$ (the current temperature in container) as a function of $V_\text{in}$. This curve behaves sensibly and lends confidence to the model.

The question is: How to do this analytically?

i.e. How can we obtain a $\Theta_\text{final}(V_\text{in})$, ie the final temperature after $V_\text{in}$ amount of water is added/mixed/overflowed. It seems a definite integral from $0$ to $V_\text{in}$ is required, but the multiple $dV_\text{in}$'s are confusing the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please see how to format equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136). For now I've edited your question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your little model is correct (I believe it is). I've used slightly less bulky symbols:

$$T+\mathrm{d}T=\frac{CT+T_0\mathrm{d}V}{C+\mathrm{d}V}$$
$$(T+\mathrm{d}T)(C+\mathrm{d}V)=CT+T_0\mathrm{d}V$$
$$CT+T\mathrm{d}V+C\mathrm{d}T+\mathrm{d}T\mathrm{d}V=CT+T_0\mathrm{d}V$$
$$\text{with }\mathrm{d}T\mathrm{d}V\approx 0$$
$$T\mathrm{d}V+C\mathrm{d}T=T_0\mathrm{d}V$$
$$C\mathrm{d}T=(T_0-T)\mathrm{d}V$$
$$\boxed{\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T-T_0}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{C}}$$
Now integrate both sides on appropriate interval; $(0,T_i)\text{ and }(V,T(V))$:

$$\ln\Big[\frac{T(V)-T_0}{T_i-T_0}\Big]=-\frac{V}{C}$$
$$\boxed{T(V)=T_0+(T_i-T_0)e^{-V/C}}$$

**Note of caution:** by assuming instant mixing the model violates the universal speed limit.

Comment: Instant mixing clearly an approximation. Nice way of making the DE separable. I can't get that to produce a sensible end result though. What we expect from common sense, and the numerical analysis, is for T -> T0 as V-> inf  ie asymptote to the incoming temperature. 

Integrating your DE seems to give me exp growth?  Oh wait... a minus sign appeared... edited?

Comment: Hi. The integral behaves perfectly as you expected: exponential decay with $T=T_0$ as asymptote for $V\to +\infty$. This made me know the solution is correct. If you find otherwise you have a sign error somwhere.

Comment: Yes, I had a minus error, now edited.

Comment: Yes, Your earlier version was missing the minus sign on RHS, and I didn't pick up that small error. So yes it's decay with asymtote now. Just got to figure out how to do the limits now, given it's 2 diff variables?? Or just use a differentiat equn approach with "initial conditions"

Comment: Initial conditions: $T=T_i$ and $V=0$, then integrate to $T(V)$ and $V$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That all checks out and agrees with the numerical analysis. Answer accepted. I might post an answer using the original symbols and showing how to finish the integration and determine the (single) integration constant using initial conditions. 

All looks much like "capacitor charging" to me...but then that's a EEE POV ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the accept. All these problems like cap. disch, Newtonian cooling, radio. decay are very similar.